# HTML / rich text editor in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Is there a way to have a rich text editor in the Django admin panel, as a widget for a TextField, instead of TextArea, as the admin will essentially put in a text that would be HTML text

it would basically be an HTML formatted email that would be sent out each time a certain row is created in the database table, and admin would manually input this HTML content

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although there are lots of rich text editors(django plugins) available for admin site(like its mentioned in @obayhan's answer), I love to use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), and its a JS based editor, so its not required to install any django apps. [Here](https://ruddra.com/richtext-editor-in-django-admin-site/) its written about how to use it on admin site.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of wysiwyg editors. Listed in here >> https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/